# Mean by levels of 2 factors

Tags: r

I'd like to obtain the mean of a response variable I'll arbitrarily call `value` for a particular level of one factor, say, `condition`, and a particular level of another factor, say, `train`.

I understand that `mean(data$value[data$condition=="a"])` is one way to obtain the mean of value for group `a`, but my question is how to obtain the mean of `value` for condition `a` and, say, train `c`. I would like to use a similar indexing structure  as `mean(data$value[data$condition=="a"])`.

I've tried, as an example, `mean(data$value[data$condition=="a"][data$train=="c"])` but that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Combine the two conditions with a logical _and_: `mean(data$value[data$condition=="a" & data$train=="c"]) `?

Comment: Or, since the question seems to be imprecise, you are trying to calculate means by group. In such case, you could use `by()` function: `by(data$value, data$condition, mean)`.

Answer (score 0):

the `by` command is a good option suggested by kaksat but a faster option is `tapply`. 
So your results would look something like

```
tapply(data$value, data$condition, mean)
```

Some quick micro benchmarking tests:

```
x = c(rnorm(5), runif(5))
y = rep(c('a','b'), each = 5)

 microbenchmark(
   by(x, y, mean)
 )
Unit: microseconds
           expr     min       lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
 by(x, y, mean) 266.648 284.1415 300.5616 292.702 306.256 671.369   100
 microbenchmark(
   tapply(x,y,mean)
 )
Unit: microseconds
               expr    min     lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
 tapply(x, y, mean) 83.108 85.584 92.65721 87.3725 97.2045 284.738   100
```